# This code snippet failed on a test of 0, can anyone tell me why and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
const dayOfWeek = moment().tz(timezone).format('d');
```

//test for weekend
// 0 = sunday, 6=saturday

```
if ((dayOfWeek === 0 ) || (dayOfWeek == 6)
    {
        response = "closed";
    }
        else
    {
        response = "open";
    }
```

this part {dayOfWeek === 0) failed to test TRUE, really not sure why

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did == 0 work?  Need to understand the difference between == and ===

Comment: check typeof dayOfWeek. if it's not number, then that's why it fails.

Comment: `moment().format()` returns a string. You have `dayOfWeek === "0"`, not `dayOfWeek === 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if dayOfWeek is 0 (number) or '0' (string). I see that for the next check you use `==` and not `===`. Have a look at [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)